# mongoclient.connection does not return cursor back on command line

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

This is my test1.js

```
console.log("foo");
```

When I run the test1.js, I got the command line back

```
$ node test2.js
foo
$
```

This is my test2.js, using MongoDbClient

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://local.host/test?w=1", function(err, db) {
   console.log("foo");
});
```

However when I run test2.js, I have to press CTRL-C to get the command line back

```
$ node test3.js
foo
^C
$
```

What's the difference? and What should I do to get the command line back(close connection, maybe)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js will not close application while there is some events subscribed and potential logic can happen.

When you create MongoClient it creates EventEmitter as well and it will not let node.js process to exit as it potentially can receive some events.

If you want to get cursor back - then you have few options:

1. Nicely kill all EventEmitters and idling timers and intervals and process will then exit. But it is hard to achieve.
2. Just call: `process.exit(0)` which will nicely close process.

As well check `ref` and `unref` for timer functions (interval, timeout): http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_unref

In case with MongoClient, just close database connection when you are done with it:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb', function(err, db) {
  // do your stuff

  // when you are done with database, make sure to respect async queries:
  db.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but confused. Is this right behaviour? Normally when callback is finished, it should return a value and kill the timer in JS, i.e. ajax call, etc. I don't see why MongoClient does it differently?

Comment: By calling `MongoClient.connect` it will create connection to database as well as EventEmitter, and while this connection is open it will not let node.js process to exit. MongoClient uses mongodb.Db class which is very big https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/db.js
So it has a lot of stuff going on there. It is not as simple as just timer functions.