# How do I finish execution from within a promise in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

Tinkering with a command land NPM app. It's only 12 lines and I'm stuck.
Once I enter into my promise, the app continues to run rather than letting me type into command line again (until cmd+C of course). Not sure what to google to find answer myself so hopefully code below is enough!

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/building';

console.log(process.argv);

MongoClient.connect(dbUrl)
.then(function(db){
  console.log('connected to db!');
  // I guess there is some command to run here? 
  // Promise resolution of sorts?
  return;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In node.js, the process will continue to run by itself if you have timers still running, servers still running or sockets still open.

You can manually exit your program at any time with [`process.exit()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) even if some of the above items are still running/open.

Or, you can `unref()` any of the above three items to instruct node.js to NOT wait for that specific resource to be closed before exiting the program.

So, in your specific case with the DB connection, you can:

1. Call `process.exit()` to manually exit the program.
2. Close the DB connection so node.js won't have anything to wait for
3. Call `.unref()` on the DB socket to tell node.js not to wait for this resource.

FYI, this is a very similar question: [mongoclient.connection does not return cursor back on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746444/mongoclient-connection-does-not-return-cursor-back-on-command-line)

Comment: I approved after reading Friday night, but actually tested today :) Both `process.exit()` and closing connection works

Answer (score 1):

Node will keep running until you explicitly disconnect from mongodb. To do that, call `db.close()`.